# Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin 'my_page' in a call to 'postMessage'

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, postmessage

i have following script

**Parent Page(pair_pixel_filter.php):**

```
 window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
            $('#log').append("Received message: " + (e.data));
        }, false);
 $('.photo-upload-btn').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
        });
```

**The Child Page**

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: {
                base64data: dataURL
            },
            success: function(data) {
                window.opener.postMessage(data, "pair_pixel_filter.php");
                window.close(); }
        });
```

Basically opening a Popup and then doing some ajax on pop up and returning result to parent. But from Child i am getting this error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin 'pair_pixel_filter.php' in a call to 'postMessage'

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The 2nd parameter to `postMessage` is the "target origin".  This is the *domain* where the page is located, not the name of the (php) file.

It needs to be something like:

```
window.opener.postMessage(data, "http://example.com");
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: very true, i just found out that we need to pass Full path like `localhost/abc/mypage.php`

Comment: @noobie-php actually, javascript will ignore anything after the domain, so the target window will accept it if the host is localhost, even if the path is different. Therefore, passing `http://localhost/abc/mypage.php` as origin will have same effect as passing `http://localhost` or `http://localhost/literally/anything/xyz.php`.

Comment: But you do need to include the port number

Comment: @Dave Only if it's non-standard.  Just like you'd normally type a URL into the browser.