# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin

Tags: html, iframe, sandbox, postmessage

I have the iframe:

```
<iframe id="GameFrame" 
sandbox="allow-scripts allow-pointer-lock" 
src="https://127.0.0.1:112/games/1047/play">
</iframe>
```

My parent page is located at:

```
https://127.0.0.1/arcade/not-hidden/space-blaster-1047
```

I'm trying to post a message to the iFrame:

```
var gameIframe = $("#GameFrame");
gameIframe.get(0).contentWindow.postMessage("screenshot", "");
```

But this throws the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin '' in a call to 'postMessage'.

Other attempts:

```
postMessage("screenshot", "https://127.0.0.1");
```

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://127.0.0.1') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').

How can I get this posting a message to the iFrame?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373376/uncaught-syntaxerror-failed-to-execute-postmessage-on-window-invalid-targe

Answer (score 5):

Just figured this out right now, need to use `*` as the origin:

```
gameIframe.get(0).contentWindow.postMessage("screenshot", "*");
```

Comment: Be aware of the dangers of using "*" for the target.  This allows any JS to receieve the message by implementing `addEventListener('message'...)`.

MDN has details on how to securely use `postMessage`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: I am getting "Protocols, domains, and ports must match" error on Safari, even though I postMessage to * target origin. Other browsers work. Is wildcard target not supported by Safari? What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I run the code locally (in a local directory), but when I put it in a webserver (Tomcat), the code works.